# mysql logs showing strange attempts at getting access to mysql server potentially. If so, How to determine source?

Tags: mysql, security

Does the below indicate a security threat?  If so, how can I block it?

```
2018-10-25T18:54:50.549213Z 217151 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T18:54:50.783917Z 217153 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:24.779369Z 218340 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:25.271370Z 218344 [Note] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:25.746069Z 218348 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:26.720098Z 218353 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:27.204406Z 218358 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:27.681921Z 218361 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:28.162192Z 218364 [Note] Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:28.651509Z 218368 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:29.146605Z 218372 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:30.124145Z 218377 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:30.615942Z 218379 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:31.105515Z 218382 [Note] Access denied for user 'popa3d'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:31.601103Z 218386 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:32.081792Z 218389 [Note] Access denied for user 'joomla'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:32.575698Z 218393 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:33.067957Z 218396 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:33.555079Z 218398 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:34.031557Z 218402 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-10-25T19:00:34.519629Z 218407 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: its been accessed by localhost. Work out what is accessing it. Could be just a script with a wrong config

Comment: @danblack It isn't obvious to me from the log entry that `localhost` isn't just a string being sent by the attacker. With a comparison between a log entry for a local access and a remote access, your comment could potentially be turned into an answer.

Comment: The reason it says localhost is that PhpmyAdmin accesses mysql via apache via php, so on localhost.   Even though it is ultimately coming from the web, being passed in through the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I searched my server for other instances of joomla, etc.  This revealed thousands of entries like the following in the apache access logs.

`142.93.210.85 - - [25/Oct/2018:19:00:29 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?pma_username=root&pma_password=1234 HTTP/1.1" 200 12100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"`

So a script kiddie in India (or proxying through India) was going after php my admin.  Will do the following to add whitelisting in /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf

https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/public-cloud-forum/7386/configuring-phpmyadmin-with-restricted-ip-access

Comment: I would consider simply uninstalling the vulnerable software.